# Eureka instance appname not working with Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

It seems like gateway can't resolve application registered in eureka server using eureka.instance.appname. In our case we have applications deployed in two different environment (uat and qa) but both will register on one clustered eureka server. We differentiate the applications from two environments using eureka.instance.appname. One is registered as service_app_uat and another one as service_app_qa however the spring.application.name is service.app. Eureka is able to register the app from two different environment just fine but Spring Cloud Gateway can't resolve these two registered instances from eureka. However if we removed the eureka.instance.appname both app from two environments registered as service_app with two instances which we don't want.

Is there any other way to register application in Eureka with custom service name?

Comment: It's not an issue with eureka, but how we read the values out of eureka, we only use application name. It would be an enhancement to use instance.appname

Comment: Yes exactly, it is an issue with Spring Cloud Gateway eureka implementation. The reason you can set eureka instance app name is for the scenario we have above. One application can have different deployed profiles that register to one Eureka Server. We are hoping that this will be implemented in spring cloud gateway soon. We are doing too much unnecessary redundancy in our properties because of this.

Comment: No, it's an enhancement to how spring cloud netflix implements discovery client and such, not gateway. Please open an issue

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just utilize Spring Profiles and provide different naming via spring.application.name?

Comment: We did, spring.application.name is working perfectly with spring cloud gateway. However like i said above we have this scenario where we are deploying the application in two different environment and have to be registered with different service name. We can't change the spring.application.name for each environment because it is being used by spring config server. So if the app_server deployed in uat (active profile is set to uat) the server config will retrieve app_server-uat.yml properties, same goes to qa environment.

Comment: For eureka registration we are hoping to rely on the eureka.instance.appname to differentiate between the two, registered on same eureka server. Thanks for the response, btw.